# update table with prepared statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to update my cards table. After the user selects the "update" button it redirects him to the update page where he can see and modify his datas. the problem is, that input fields don't load his datas and also can't update them for some reason. Here's the button on the first page:

```
<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-succes" role="button">Edit</a>
```

and here's the update page:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'reg');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("HIBA: Nem sikerült csatlakozni. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE cards SET name=?, phone=?, phone2=?, email=?, zipcode=?, address=?, job=?, description=?, visibility=?, confirmed=?, userid=?  WHERE id = ?');



if (
    $stmt &&
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssisssiiii', $name, $phone, $phone2, $email, $zipcode, $address, $job, $description, $visibility, $confirmed, $userid, $id)
    &&
    $stmt -> execute() &&
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM cards WHERE id='$id'") &&
    $result = $stmt -> get_result() 
) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $phone2 = $row['phone2'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $job = $row['job'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
        echo 'Updated';
    }

 else {
    echo $mysqli -> error;
}
?>
 <form action="update.php" method="post">
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="tblSaveForm">
<tr class="header">
<td colspan="2">Edit Card</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Username</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['name']; ?>">
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>phone</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['phone']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<td><label>phone2</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone2" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['phone2']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>email</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['email']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>zipcode</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="zipcode" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['zipcode']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>address</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['address']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>job</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="job" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['job']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>description</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $result['description']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="buttom"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and here's where datas coming from:

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, phone, phone2, email, zipcode, address, job, description, visibility, confirmed, userid FROM cards WHERE userid= ?");
          $stmt->bind_param("i",$userid);
          $userid = (int) $_SESSION['id'];
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->get_result();

            while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            ?>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-profile">
                <div class="card-avatar">
                  <a href="#">
                  <img class="img" src="assets/img/faces/avatar.png" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-top">
                  <h4 class="card-category text-gray"><b><?php echo $record['job']; ?></b><br>
                    <span style="color: black;"><?php echo $record['name']; ?></span></h4>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <h5 class="card-description">
                  <i class="material-icons">
                      mobile_friendly
                      </i>
                      <b>tel.:</b> <?php echo $record['phone']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description"  <?php if(empty($record['phone2'])){echo " style='display: none';"; }?>>
                  <i class="material-icons">
                      mobile_friendly
                      </i>
                      <b>tel2.:</b> <?php echo $record['phone2']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description" <?php if(empty($record['email'])){echo " style='display: none';"; }?>>
                      <i class="material-icons">
                        email
                        </i>
                        <b> E-mail:</b> <?php echo $record['email']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description" <?php if(empty($record['address'])){echo " style='display: none';"; }?>>
                        <i class="material-icons">
                            location_on
                            </i>
                          <b> Cím:</b> <?php echo $record['address']; ?>
                      </h5>
                    <h5 class="card-description">
                        <b> Leírás:</b> <?php echo $record['description']; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="card-buttons">
                  <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Biztosan törölni szeretné?');">
                     <input value="<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" name="id" style="display: none;">
                     <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-succes" role="button">Edit</a>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="reject" id="update" style="background-color: red;">Törlés</button>

                  </form>
```

Comment: Is the table inside a `<form>`?

Comment: Where do you set all the variables that you're using in `bind_param()`?

Comment: Why do you use `foreach ($result as $row)`? There should only be one row, you don't need a loop.

Comment: 1. No, I missed that. Just added ```<form action="update.php" method="post">```           2. Those are coming from the other page I'll edit my main question with it's code.           3. Should I just  simply delete foreach?

Comment: You need `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: You're missing something like `$name = $_POST['name'];`.

Comment: In a while loop like ``` while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {?>                      //table here }?>

Comment: Could you please show it on my code?

Comment: That loop is used for displaying the form from the database, not getting the user input when they submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the code that puts the user input into all the variables that are used in the `UPDATE` statement. And the update should only be used when the form is submitted, not when you're initially displaying the form.

You need to put the `id` into the URL in the `action` attribute of the form, so it knows which ID to update.

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'reg');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("HIBA: Nem sikerült csatlakozni. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $job = $_POST['job'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $visibility = $_POST['visibility'];
    $confirmed = $_POST['confirmed'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE cards SET name=?, phone=?, phone2=?, email=?, zipcode=?, address=?, job=?, description=?, visibility=?, confirmed=?, userid=?  WHERE id = ?');

    if (
        $stmt &&
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssisssiiii', $name, $phone, $phone2, $email, $zipcode, $address, $job, $description, $visibility, $confirmed, $userid, $id) &&
        $stmt -> execute()
        ) {
        echo 'Updated';
    } else {
        echo $mysqli -> error;
    }
} 

$getstmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE id= ?");
if ($getstmt and
    $getstmt->bind_param('i', $id) and
    $getstmt->execute() and
    $result = $getstmt->get_result() and
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
    ) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $phone2 = $row['phone2'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $job = $row['job'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];


    ?>
    <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="tblSaveForm">
    <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Edit Card</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Username</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>phone</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <td><label>phone2</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone2" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $phone2; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>email</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>zipcode</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="zipcode" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $zipcode; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>address</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>job</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="job" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $job; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>description</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="buttom"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: I've got this warning message with this: ```Warning: mysqli_stmt::prepare() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\update.php on line 46``` If I change it  to ```$getstmt->prepare('$id)``` all I got is a white page.

Comment: That line should be `bind_param`.

Comment: Yes it solved that but I'm getting another error now: ```Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\update.php on line 49

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\update.php:49 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\update.php on line 49```

Comment: Use `and` instead of `&&` to get the proper operator precedence.

Comment: Yes it's working now, but only two things appears on the screen. The Edit Card and the Username subtitle. https://gyazo.com/d51abc83b9418ba57b5557d5e1f0f911

Comment: Do you see the rest in View Source?

Comment: No, this is all I see there: https://gyazo.com/f3c36a6d68d34ea73117603ff327d0f2

Comment: That's the Elements panel, I said View Source. There's probably an HTML syntax error somewhere that's preventing it from parsing the rest of the table.

Comment: There was a missing `</td>` after the `name` input.

Comment: Yes, just found it aswell but still getting this: https://gyazo.com/156b0a66294a1e24e93c9262c41e5fb1 and also if I delete the Username table, this error drops: https://gyazo.com/148beea05f5e667253e83dc1eca46812

Comment: `$result['name']` should just be `$name`.